# How many Stardust are there, and what do I get for collecting them all?

Tags: legend-of-dragoon

I am playing through legend of dragoon (for the playstation 1) and forgot how many stardust there are in the game. Additionally, would someone be able to provide the rewards for each amount of stardust collected? I think that there are around 50, and the collection of all of them unlocks a secret boss, but I am not too sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 50 stardust in the game. For every 10 that you collect, you can visit Martel to gain a new accessory.

- 10 stardust -    Physical Ring (Raises maximum HP 50%)
- 20 stardust -    Amulet (Doubles maximum MP)
- 30 stardust -    Wargod Sash (Raises SP by 50%)
- 40 stardust -    Rainbow Earring (Prevents all abnormal status)
- 50 stardust -    Vanishing Stone (Gives access to Magician Faust, an optional boss at the Tower of Flanvel in Kashua Glacier.)

This article in the Legend of Dragoon wiki provides more information on Stardust, as well as a guide on where to find all 50.

http://legendofdragoon.wikia.com/wiki/Stardust

Comment: perfect. Just what I was looking for. Now to actually find all the things without cheating... Takes forever